# Regarding TimeZoneInfo Class (Framework 3.5) - Related to Daylight Savings Time

Tags: timezone, dst

I have a doubt regarding daylight savings time applicable to the North American region time zones:

**The scenario is:**

I have to work between lets say the following time zones:  Eastern Time (UTC-5.00) and Mountain Time (UTC - 7:00).

Generally the daylight savings time adjustment of +1 hour will be applicable from 2nd Sunday of March for the said time zones.

Case 1: Initially the time zones are 2 hours apart

Case 2: On 10th March 2013 (2nd Sunday of March this year) exactly after the time 1:59:59 AM, the time will be 3:00 AM (because of daylight savings time adjustment) hence for the next 2 hours these time zones (Eastern and Mountain) will be 3 hours apart.

**What I am doing:**

I create a file in a machine X (under Eastern Time) and then I send this file to a different machine Y (under Mountain Time). This transfer operation consumes negligible time. After the file is received at Y. The creation time of the file is read (which will obviously give the Eastern Time) and then this time is converted to the Mountain Time with the help of ConvertTime method of TimeZoneInfo class and the result is stored in DB. This works just perfect.

**What is my concern:**

When I create a file during such a time when daylight savings time adjustment is applicable for the Eastern Time and not for the Mountain Time (Read Case 2 above), will I still be getting the correct Mountain Time equivalent for the specific Eastern Time with the same ConvertTime method of TimeZoneInfo class or is there anything else that I need to take care of?.

Hope I made myself clear, if not please do ask.

Seeking for a explanation to my doubt :)

Regards,

Vikas